# Can't login to the router once the connection is established using telnet

Tags: router, login, telnet

I'm trying to login to the router using telnet. Connection is successfully established and I'm asked for the login but nothing happens afterwards. I enter the username and it seems like it just looped back.

```
********************************************
** Device Model  : zxic                   **
** Mac Address   : 70:a5:6a:7b:31:ad      **
** Soft Version  : V1.1.0_251             **
** Build Date    : 2022-08-17 16:52:15    **
********************************************
Login: admin
Login:
Login:
Login:
Login:
Login: admin
Login:
Login:
Login:
Login:
Login:
```

Comment: Which router is it and is its firmware fully updated?

Comment: Why are you accessing a router via `telnet`? **There is no secure implementation of Telnet** - SSH should always be used, and Telnet should be disabled and removed because it's a security risk _(Telnet sends all data via plaintext, including the passphrase for `root`)_

Comment: It's a C-Data | Model No. FD504GW-DX-Z416.

Comment: And there is no SSH.